# AWS Lambda throws IllegalStateException: Missing HTTP method for Quarkus Amazon Lambda HTTP Api

Tags: http, aws-lambda, quarkus

I am creating a Quarkus amazon lambda HTTP to do some stuff but I am getting the error

For routing, I am using Funqy and the start-API using lambda is working perfectly but when I invoke the API with sam invoke and was already pushed and published in AWS Lambda is still getting this error.
My goal is to create an HTTP API quarkus amazon lambda, thanks for the help

```
__  ____  __  _____   ___  __ ____  ______
 --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/
 -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/
2022-04-01 20:12:47,190 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) json-transposition-tool-quarkus-http-aws-lambda 1.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.7.0.Final) started in 4.149s.
2022-04-01 20:12:47,192 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated.
2022-04-01 20:12:47,192 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [amazon-lambda, cdi, funqy-http, security, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]
2022-04-01 20:12:47,225 ERROR [qua.ama.lam.http] (main) Request Failure: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing HTTP method in request event
        at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.http.LambdaHttpHandler.nettyDispatch(LambdaHttpHandler.java:176)
        at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.http.LambdaHttpHandler.handleRequest(LambdaHttpHandler.java:63)
        at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.http.LambdaHttpHandler.handleRequest(LambdaHttpHandler.java:43)
        at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.AmazonLambdaRecorder.handle(AmazonLambdaRecorder.java:79)
        at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler.handleRequest(QuarkusStreamHandler.java:58)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$StreamMethodRequestHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:375)
        at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:899)
        at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:262)
        at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:199)
        at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.main(AWSLambda.java:193)
```

Comment: Sounds like you are not using proxy integration in AWS API Gateway: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html

Comment: Yes, the problem was a misconception of how the HTTP API and REST API works, but right now I am not mixing settings for the lambda and it is working properly

Comment: Using the Rest approach, lambda up and running!

Comment: @JosueRojasVega hi, could you please specify where exactly you found the issue, I faced the same problem, got stuck